# Adverb used as an adjective? avare

Tags: adverb

In Martial, there is a line *Erras, meorum fur avare librorum...* and it seems that *avare* is an adverb but this makes no sense since the intention seems to be modifying *fur* in which case I would have expected *fur avarus*, not *fur avare*. What is the grammar here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here *avare* is not an adverb but an adjective in the vocative case, in agreement with *fur*, which is also vocative.

Comment: Scansion helps making the distinction. The final *-e* is short in the vocative and long in the adverb.